# ajax not being deferred with when

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I am trying to get ajax to defer and only return when the list of Ajax's have completed.  This is what I sort of have (note it's not the real script as there is much to that one, this is only the part I'm not getting to work right in a form I can put up on SO)

```
    function start_search(){
        var self=this;//hold to preserve scop
        var wsu_search = self._get_globals('wsu_search').refresh();
        var search_input = self._get_globals('search_input').refresh();
        var term = wsu_search.find('input').val();
        var queries = Array();
        self.search_options.data=[];
        $.each(self.search_options.providers, function(i,provider){
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.options.termTemplate = (typeof(provider.termTemplate) !== undefined && provider.termTemplate !== "") ? provider.termTemplate : undefined;
            queries.push(run_query(term,provider));
        });
        //$.whenAll(queries)
        var defer=$.when.apply($, queries).done(
        function(){
            return self.search_options.data;
        });

    }

    function run_query(term,provider){
        var self=this;//hold to preserve scop
        var search_input = self._get_globals('search_input').refresh();
        var result = [];

        if(typeof(provider)!==undefined && typeof(provider.url)!==undefined && provider.nodes===undefined){
            $.ajax({
                url: provider.url,
                dataType: provider.dataType,
                data: {
                    related:self.search_options.search.getRelated
                },
                success:function(data){
                    var proData=self.setup_result_obj(term,data);
                    $.merge(self.search_options.data,proData);
                }
            });
        }else{
            //self.search_options.data.push(result);
        }
    }

    start_search();
```

What happens is that the `.done()` part always hits before the `success` hits.  When I have break points on this, I can see that each of the `run_query()`'s gets added to the `var queries = Array();` and happens before the  `.done()`.  After they are added then it will hit the break on `$.ajax({` , which is good.  Here is the but, so it hits the `.done()` then it hits the break point I set on `$.merge()` under `success:function(data){}`

Any ideas on how to get passed this?  so far nothing on SO has helped and I'm at a wall.

Comment: At first place: why do you combine deferreds and `success`?

Comment: are you meaning why am I using them both?

Comment: because there is not good example out there that really shows what come in `.done()` when you use one or more `$.ajax`, the why is cause I'm trying to solve the issue :)

Comment: ok I think I get it, drop the success and in the defer use `$.each(arguments,function(){});` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the line

```
queries.push(run_query(term,provider));
```

meaningful, `run_query` should return a promise.

The promise that should be returned is the object returned by the `$.ajax()`, ie.

```
return $.ajax({
    ...
});
```

You may also want to return a promise from the `else{...}` clause.

Comment: may apologies I had picked that up yesterday that was one of the missing pieces.  The other was that @zerkms was right on the usage of the `success`.  thank you for getting back